# How Can I Maximize the Number of Concurrent Requests That My Domino 9 Server Handles?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have noticed when calling a Java Servlet ([this](http://planetlotus.org/profiles/jason-hook_111993) type) or an XPage with an ExtLib REST Service custom control in it, the server responds to only 6 requests at a time.

The way I have been testing the server is to open around 30 tabs in Google Chrome with Dev Tools open to disable the cache, and get network times. I have a Chrome extension that refreshes all the tabs at once. I refresh all tabs and keep track of the tab response times.

The service I am calling returns a lot of address book entries, I typically pass a parameter of 20000 or 40000 which is the number of entries returned.

An entry being of the form:
  {"$21":"","@UNID":"ECABACF30AAB898085257BFD006EF2E2","$12":"","CompanyName":"","$16":"Jeffery Aaron/ROCKALL","@position":"5","$17":"Aaron , Jeffery","$18":"0.0"}

Comment: When your server is busy, type "tell http xsp javadump" command on console several times. With help of XPages Portable Command Guide (excerpt here: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/lotus-notes/9780132943062/chapter-3dot-working-with-the-console/ch03lev1sec2) analyze logs. It will answer whether problem is in serialization of Java code or semaphores in Domino API.

Comment: Is that 6 requests on the same session? Or do you mean 6 different sessions (ie. users)?

Comment: Same Session (Same User)